# Is PIN caching acceptable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, web-services, security, smartcard

I have a web service that prompts for the user credentials (PIN) before requesting for the smart card.
My question is: Are there any security guidelines regarding PIN caching?

Answer (score 1):

PIN caching is on the convenience side of the security vs. convenience scale. Asking for the PIN before the card is even known is at the very least suspicious. Caching is in general weakening the security and one has to decide, whether that is acceptable: what are you trying to prove with PIN entry and is it sufficient to know, that the card holder was present earlier?